# Scrape `HTTPS` websites with HTTP proxy using HttpClient

Tags: c#, web-scraping, httpclient, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape an `https` website using `http` proxy provided here https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/?country=US&type=hs#list

The website I am trying to scrape is also https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/?country=US&type=hs#list
however, no matter which website I try to scrape it doesn't work as long as it has `https` but any website with `http` it does work fine. I tried using `https` proxy but it is still not supported in .NET core according to https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2043#issuecomment-1021597346

This is my code and what I have tried so far.

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

internal sealed class TestProxy {
        private HttpClientHandler _htttpClientHandler;
        private HttpClient _client;

        internal Test {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            var proxy = new WebProxy
            {
                Address = new Uri($"http://173.82.153.196:16781"), // This proxy is working as of 12/13/2022
                BypassProxyOnLocal = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
            };

            this._htttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseProxy = true,
                UseCookies = true,
                Proxy = proxy,
                DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
            };

            _htttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

            this._client = new HttpClient(this._htttpClientHandler, true);
       }

 private async Task<HtmlDocument> LoadPage(string url)
        {
            this._client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0");

            var stream = await this._client.GetStreamAsync(url);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);
                return doc;
            }
        }

}
```

I keep getting an exception with error code `400` or `403` such as

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).'
```

I am pretty sure there has to be a solution, no? I searched google and stackoverflow with no luck.

Comment: 403 has nothing to do with https. 403 means that your code needs to send some kind of credentials, usually via an `Authorization` header.

Comment: @StephenCleary I understand. but not in this case. Even if I request `https://www.google.com` I get 403. Now the `Authorization` could be the proxy credentials. However, this is the case with ALL free proxies that can be found here `https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/?country=US&type=hs#list` or any other website that provide proxies. Also, I did mention that I also get different error codes such as `400`, not a single proxy so far has been able to retrieve an `https`; However, using the exact same proxy to retrieve `HTTP` works just fine. You can replicate it by copying the code.

Comment: @StephenCleary by copying the code and calling the function `LoadPage` on any url you desire and you will see what I am talking about.